# I want to launch a programme at Sunrise

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I want to start a recording 30 mins before Sunrise and terminate 1 Hr after Sunrise.

I've written a shell script to get sunrise & set from weather.com and use this to set Times in crontab to trigger the app and then kill it at appropriate times. I would like to automate this. at, atrun, atd could be used, I suppose, but don't seem like the right tools.

Ideally cron would get the times and I could use these directly as say, Sunrise-0.5 and Sunrise+1, in crontab.

How can i achieve my objective?

Thanks  FedonKadifeli  yes it could be done this way and the script can be re-arranged to give only the time for sunrise today and then use at to run the recording. I was looking for a simpler way. But Hey time is short. I'll give it a try. No this doesn't work it requires manual input, and I'm not awake at 4:30 in the summer and this would just switch starting recording at dawn for starting at at dawn.

I need this to be fully automatic throughout the year updating the time of sunrise every now and then, e.g. weekly. I live in the UK where sunrise varies depending on time of year from approx. 4:30am to 9:30am. At the moment I achieve this by modifying the crontab entry when I remember. The time doesn't change much day to day but I would like to remove my memory from the process.

Comment: It depends on your script: on how it gets the sunrise time, when and for what date. However, I presume `cron` would be appropriate for your script and `at` for your recoding process.

Comment: It's a SMOP. Run a `cron` job at midnight that fetches the times, computes the offsets  and uses `at` to schedule the events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machine is not on 24/7 so cron is not usefull.
I have used Anacron with a period of 1 and a delay of 7. This does the job bjut a day late for dawn. In the UK ~52deg N the dawn doesn't change that quickly so starting a minute or so early is not important. Changing between Dec and June is!

Solved

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for guidelines in bash scripting and crontab, [eyesome](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome) is a good study:

- Daily it obtains sunrise and sunset times from dateandtime.com. The times are stored in files which you can display in `conky` if you wish.
- It is called through `anacron` like you are using now.
- It runs on boot, sleeping hours between sunrise and sunset.
- It starts processing at sunrise and sunset and continues processing for a user defined period, sleeping 1 minute inbetween.
- It dims/brightens multiple monitors and sets their color temperature. You don't need this feature but you can change it to make your recording.